# PowerShell array iteration or parsing problem?

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I'm new to PowerShell. I'm trying to pull a users Active Directory info based on their job title and place it in a csv file. I have two corresponding arrays, $title and $csvfile. $title[0] corresponds with $csvfile[0] and $title[1] to $csvfile[1] and so on. This loop creates all my .csv files but doesn't pull any user data.  I can manually enter any of the $title items into the script and it works but when used as an array I get nothing.

Does an array add any leading or ending spaces, quotations, delimiters, anything that might keep the -and statement from working?

```
$title = @(
   'Director of Nursing'
   'Assistant Director of Nursing'
   'Activities Director'
)
   $csvfile = @(
  'DON'
  'ADON'
  'ACTIVITIES'
)

    for($i=0; $i -lt $title.Count; $i++)
{
    #Get-ADUser -Filter { (Title -like "Director of Nursing")  -and  (Company -like "location1") }| Export-Csv c:\temp\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"
    Get-ADUser -filter { (Title -like "$($title[$i])")  -and  (Company -like "Location1") }| Export-Csv "c:\tempPath\$($csvfile[$i]).csv"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD module re-parses the `-Filter` block (and turns it into a proper LDAP filter), the likeliest explanation is that it can't resolve `$($title[$i])` when that happens.

Try with a string filter instead:

```
Get-ADUser -filter "Title -like '$($title[$i])'  -and  Company -like 'Location1'"| ...
```

Comment: @Mathias, where did you find this out from?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I used [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to decompile the AD module assembly and had a look at what it does

Comment: hmm, does it just break down the code they use? Sorry, cant get to it on our network at work. Might import it and have it read as a function so I can see the code if that's the case. Thank you!